# UIimagepicker Controller selecting images dynamically

Tags: ios, xcode

How to select images from the iphone library?i want to store them in an array and used later..please help

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest never add image to array for future use, when the number of images increase or size of image is high the application will crash.

1. Save it in doc directory and keep the path as reference
2. Add the asset url to array instead of image

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/ios-advanced-programming-the-image-picker/) for you.

If you need to store image in array add the following code in `UIImagePicker`'s `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate method:

```
[yourImageArray addObject:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
```